# Why in my ant design does not work defaultOpenKeys?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I use Ant Design -> Menu/Submenu.

And I wrote my custom function component `CustomSubMenu`, which simply shows Ant SubMenu and use it in wrapper component Menu, but prop `defaultOpenKeys` does not work for it.

If you change `defaultOpenKeys={["sub1"]}` to `defaultOpenKeys={["sub2"]}` it works, but does not work for `defaultOpenKeys={["sub1"]}`

Can you explain, why and how can I solve this problem ?

[codeSanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-hoover-h9jm1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/friendly-cerf-dpbko?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

You need to add `key` attribute into `CustomSubMenu` component.

```
<CustomSubMenu key='sub1' />
```

and then

```
const CustomSubMenu = ({ ...props }) => {
  return (
    <Menu.SubMenu title={<span>Navigation One</span>} {...props}>
      <Menu.Item key="5">Option 5</Menu.Item>
      <Menu.Item key="6">Option 6</Menu.Item>
    </Menu.SubMenu>
  );
};
```

Later in the code

```
<>
  <Menu defaultOpenKeys={["sub1"]} mode="inline" theme="dark">
    <Menu.Item key="1">
      <span>Option 1</span>
    </Menu.Item>

    <CustomSubMenu key='sub1' />

    <SubMenu key="sub2" title="Submenu">
      <Menu.Item key="11">Option 11</Menu.Item>
      <Menu.Item key="12">Option 12</Menu.Item>
    </SubMenu>
  </Menu>
</>
```